# Crashlytics for xamarin.mac application

Tags: xamarin, crash-reports, crashlytics, xamarin.mac, google-fabric

is there any experience using Crashlytics reporting system for xamarin.mac application? I tried to create binding library, I got an exception :

> "Native linking failed with error code 1"

I'm not sure how binding library will work. any experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

At this time Fabric does not have support for Xamarin based projects. If that changes, I'll update my answer!

Comment: You can dig into the build log to determine the native linking failure reason, but if the library does not support XM then you are likely out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some info that may be of use:

> Fabric Kits available to use with Xamarin:
>
> Answers Crashlytics Digits For Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.Android and
>   Xamarin.iOS.
>
> For iOS, you need to create a application with the same bundle id on
>   XCode as the one on your Xamarin app. Then, use the Fabric Mac app to
>   add your app and complete the Kits on-boarding process.
>
> For Android, you need to create a application with the same package
>   name on android studio as the one on your Xamarin app. Then, use the
>   Fabric Mac app to add your app and complete the Kits on-boarding
>   process.
>
> After that, you can follow the instructions on
>   https://www.fabric.io/kits to configure your projects.
>
> For crashlytics on android, there is a hidden configuration, you need
>   to add/update the build id using a string resource
>
> <string
>   name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id">e9e6beb9c4284289ac68b9ab76a9ee56</string>
>
> Or else you'll get a crash on startup.
>
> There is a Sample available on Samples folder.
>
> On iOS, Crashlytics shouldn't be used with Answers. Crashlytics
>   includes Answers, so you should use either.
>
> Code is available on https://github.com/drungrin/Fabric.Sdk.Xamarin
>
> Nuget packages are also published:
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fabric/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Answers/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Crashlytics/
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Digits/

Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68256/fabric-crashlytics-answers-and-digits-for-xamarin-forms-xamarin-android-and-xamarin-ios

Answer (score 0):

a more detailed instruction following the same answer as @CMash answer could be found [here](https://alexduffell.wordpress.com/2018/06/26/using-crashlytics-with-xamarin-apps/)